# what is this error in logcat "id info cannot be read from 'Splash Screen'"?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, splash-screen, logcat

I have this in Logcat

```
2023-12-24 09:22:43.666   959-1051  BufferQueueDebug        pid-959                              E  [Splash Screen com.omarhadjsaiddev.qtappmanager#0](this:0xb40000780f8578d0,id:-1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) id info cannot be read from 'Splash Screen com.omarhadjsaiddev.qtappmanager#0'
```

I do not know where is the problem